# Do non-discrimination clauses only count for my licensees, or also for me as a copyright holder?

Tags: open-source-definition

The open source definition has a non-discrimination clause. From the [annotated Open Source Definition](http://opensource.org/osd-annotated):

> #### 5. No Discrimination Against Persons or Groups
>
> The license must not discriminate against any person or group of persons.
>
> ***Rationale:** In order to get the maximum benefit from the process, the maximum diversity of persons and groups should be equally eligible to contribute to open sources. Therefore we forbid any open-source license from locking anybody out of the process.*
>
> *Some countries, including the United States, have export restrictions for certain types of software. An OSD-conformant license may warn licensees of applicable restrictions and remind them that they are obliged to obey the law; however, it may not incorporate such restrictions itself.*

This clearly means that for a license to be considered open source, the license must not discriminate against any person or group. The license may not, for example, only allow non-profits to use the work (because non-profits are good), or disallow clowns to use the work (because clowns are creepy).

I heard people say that this also means I may not selectively license a work that I hold the copyright of under a free license. Is that true?

For example, can I grant [501(c)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/501(c)_organization) organizations an GPL-3 license to my software, but nobody else?

It is clear that according to the terms, they are allowed to re-distribute the software to anyone else, so the effectiveness of this might be low, but my question only pertains to whether or not I have the right to deny an open source license to some people/groups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As I've said before](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/912/458), software doesn't possess any licence *inherently* - it is *distributed* (or, [as the GPLv3 would have it](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/958/gpl-v3-convey-vs-gpl-v2-distribute), *conveyed*) under a licence.

You, as the copyright holder, may distribute your software under any kind of licence you want, to anyone you choose.  You may choose to distribute it only to 501(c) organisations, and only under GPLv3, if you want to.  As you correctly note, any such recipient will have the right to redistribute it to anyone they like - the GPLv3 gives them that right.  But the licence under which you distribute it to those parties doesn't force *you* to distribute it to anyone else, or indeed to anyone at all, because you aren't bound by the licence.

Comment: Amen,  brother! (+1)

Comment: ...So long as you do, indeed, hold the copyright on the entire work, i.e. you haven't incorporated contributions from other sources (unless they assigned the copyright to you, etc, etc).

Comment: @Geoff very true, though the OP stipulates that in the question.

Comment: @MadHatter Thus the "do, indeed". It's possible to believe that you own the entire copyright but fail to take into account the fact that contributions create a combined work with multiple copyright holders.

Comment: @Geoff Even if the work is a joint work, nobody has any obligation to distribute (except under some rare licenses that mandate contributing patches upstream). You can take a GPLv3 work, modify it, and refuse to distribute the modified version to anyone but clowns. Any clown who receives it would be free to distribute it to anyone else, if they so choose.

Comment: @Gilles - Unless you have distributed the compiled version, in which case, you must make the source available to those to whom you have distributed the binary, if the binary is the result of the combined work to which you don't hold the entire copyright. My point is that you *are* bound by the license if you have contributions from elsewhere (with the above caveats). If so, you can no longer refuse to provide the source to those clowns that you gave the binary to, nor can you prevent them from using the software for their (hil/nef)arious purposes.

Comment: I do not agree with the last bit “because you aren't bound by the licence.“ I believe that any recipient, including the not-for-profit can choose who to give copies to: The software holder can discriminate (you can not make me give a copy to someone), but the licence may not discriminate, to be considered an Open-Source or Free-Software licence. What you can do as a copy-right holder is “different licences to different people”.

Comment: @richard I think what you are saying is that downstream is also not forced to distribute to anyone at all, and I agree with that.  OP's question was specifically about whether clauses in the licences under which he distributed his software applied to him also ("*Do non-discrimination clauses only count for my licensees, or also for me as a copyright holder?*"), which is why I noted that **nothing** in the licences under which he chooses to distribute applies to him.

Comment: @MadHatter I think (hope) we are in agreement. I am not giving an oppositional view, just a different one. I think your view can be summed up as, you are not bound by your own licence. And mine is, even if you are it would not affect what you want to do. e.g. if a sign says “visitors must not run!”, and we ask “can the owner walk?”, then the answer is yes and yes.

Comment: @richard very well put.